# Unable to run Blackberry app in device 907 invalid cod file

Tags: java, blackberry

I just develop a blackberry application and want to run in my device.
I have been set up code signing key.And install it successfully but not able to run on my device,When I run the .jad file it says invalid cod file.
Actually what can I do now.
I am using BlackBerry_Java_Plug-in_for_Eclipse for develop.
Thanks in advanced.